How to fix this bathroom floor after it suffered water damage
My bathroom floor suffered some water damage due to failing caulking and incorrectly installed LVT next to the bathtub. I've taken out the baseboards and the top LVT layer as well as a linoleum layer under it. The subfloor below is somewhat uneven due to water damage and shows two areas <5x5inch with what looks to be mold. There is also part of the drywall that was damaged.

My plan is to cut out the subfloor next to the bathtub to remove any area with mold or water damage and check for damage underneath. The drywall at the corner I'd fix with with some joint compound, use a difficult surface primer, followed by normal primer and paint.
I would then replace the subfloor and put 1 mm underlayment in the areas where I removed the linoleum. I need to cut the LVT to leave an expansion gap and use foam spacers with 100% silicone to cover before putting in square PVC molding. For the side where it touches the acrylic bath tub, I plan to use a quarter round that has a rubber lip at the bottom and use silicone to 'glue' the quarter round on the bath tub.
Does that sound about right? Is this overkill? Should I just spray down the subfloor with mold killer before sanding it flat?

You are on the right track, the only thing I would do differently is at the tub. The floor has such a small area that if the edge at the tub is bedded in caulk to completely seal it along that edge, up and around the corner a bit, is how I would do that.
I would use a water based, high end, mildew resistant, color matched caulk to do so, keeping the joint tight, so the visible caulk line is negligible. Use something to keep the LVT pressed into the caulk until it dries completely. Once the floor is where you want it, use a well wrung out, almost to the point of dry, damp sponge to clear the excess caulk from the joint.

Thanks! Just to confirm I understand the reasoning: You mean with the overall small area, not having an expansion gap at tub is okay and unlikely to cause issues - thus flush and fully caulked? Would transparent 100% silicone be a good choice for this?

Silicone is the best for the job, but also potentially the messiest. I have used Polyseamseal for those areas and has held up well. It cleans up with water. If you feel you must use silicone and can set the floor in place with no silicone to mask the areas to keep the silicone controlled, then remove the flooring, place the silicone and press in the flooring, letting the excess ooze out of the gap at the tub, wiping it clean, then removing the tape and giving it a final wipe to smooth out  where the tape still had silicone on it. Ideally it will be wiped clean before pulling the tape.
